# Django: How do I automatically fill form input with logged in users email?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I have made a contact form and want the from_email field to be pre filled if the user is logged in.

views.py of homepage (where the form is displayed)

```
def home(request): 
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = ContactForm(request=request)
else:
    form = ContactForm(request.POST,request=request)
    if form.is_valid():
       
        subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
        from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
        message = form.cleaned_data['message']
        try:
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('success')
return render(request, "home/home.html",{'form':form})
```

forms.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ContactForm(forms.Form):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
    super(ContactForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
         email=self.request.user.email
         #self.fields["from_email"] = email

from_email = forms.EmailField(initial=email,required=True)
subject = forms.CharField(required=True)
message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea, required=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forms have a parameter called `initial` where you can pass a dictionary with the name of the field and what you want it's initial value to be. You can look at the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial) for more info. But basically you would do the following in your views.

```
def home(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm(initial={'from_email': request.user.email})
```

Comment: Thanks it works! Can you tell why we passed it only when 'request.method=Get' and why not in the 'else'?  I am new to Django so not really familiar with that request method thing.

Comment: No problem, basically by doing ```form = ContactForm(initial={'from_email': request.user.email})``` in the ```GET``` request you are passing in that initial value to the form which basically sets ```from_email```. However, in the ```POST``` you want to pass the form information to the ```data``` instead of ```initial``` to actually validate all of this. Which is done by passing ```request.POST``` which is simply a dictionary with all the data. Kinda hard to go in depth with this character limit but to better understand this I would print out the ```request.POST``` so you can see what I mean.